# C++ game returns 0 automatically

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Whenever i try to run this game, it automatically returns 0.
The game is a text-based survival game that i coded on Code::Blocks. The compiler is MinGW. I am a semi-knowledgeable programmer. There is no error when compiled.

```
// This game automatically returns 0 and ends for some reason...
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int hunger;
int warmth;
int thirst;
int choice;
// Declares variables for hunger, warmth, thirst, and the users choice

int start()
{
    cout<< "You are stuck in a forest, all alone"<< endl;
    cout<< "You must maintain your hunger, thirst, and warmth." << endl;
    int mainPage();
}

int hunt()
{
    srand(time(0));
    cout<< "You have chosen hunt!"<< endl;
    if ((rand() % 2) == 2){
        cout<< "You caught a deer!"<< endl;
        hunger = hunger + 1;
    }
    else{
        cout<< "You could not find anything..."<< endl;
    }
    int mainPage();

}
// The previous function is used for the hunting choice

int wood()
{
    cout<< "You have chosen find firewood!"<< endl;
    if ((rand() % 2) == 2){
        cout<< "You found firewood!"<<endl;
        warmth = warmth + 1;
    }
    else{
        cout<< "You could not find any firewood"<< endl;
    }
    int mainPage();
}
// Wood choice

int water()
{
    cout<< "You have chosen find water!"<< endl;

    if ((rand() % 2) == 2){
        cout<< "You have found a river!"<< endl;
        thirst = thirst + 1;

    }
    else{
        cout<< "You could not find anything..."<< endl;
    }
    int mainPage();
}
// Water choice

int mainPage()
{
    warmth = warmth - 1;
    hunger = hunger - 1;
    thirst = thirst - 1;
    // Subtracts one from each variable per turn
    if (hunger == 0){
        cout<< "You starved!"<< endl;
        cout<< "Game over!"<< endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if (thirst == 0){
        cout<< "You became dehydrated!"<< endl;
        cout<< "Game over!"<< endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if (warmth == 0){
        cout<< "You froze!"<< endl;
        cout<< "Game over!"<< endl;
        return 0;
    }
    // You die if any of the variables reach zero

    cout<< "Your hunger is"<< hunger<<  endl;
    cout<< "Your warmth is"<< warmth<<  endl;
    cout<< "Your thirst is"<< thirst<<  endl;
    cout<< "What would you like to do?"<< endl;
    cout<< "1 = hunt, 2 = find firewood, 3 = find water"<< endl;
    cin>> choice;
    if (choice = 1){
        int hunt();
    }
    if (choice = 2){
        int wood();
    }
    if (choice = 3){
        int water();
    }
    // The main page that takes the users choice as input and also tells you the amount of each variable

}
int main()
{
    hunger = 5;
    thirst = 5;
    warmth = 5;
    int start();
}
// the main function
```

Comment: _"This website said that my question is mostly code so i will copy and paste this"_ Consider there was a reason that you received this message. Undergoing it with nonsensical filler text isn't appropriate!

Comment: Have my down and close vote. Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) next time before posting a question.

Comment: I apologize, I should not have done that.

Comment: So the next step is you bang your question in shape to provide a [MCVE] exactly describing your problem and observations when debugging your code stepping through.

Comment: I dont know what part of the code is the problem, that is my problem. I am sorry if i come off a bit rude in this comment, but i simply dont know.

Comment: "semi-knowledgeable programmer" is overstating it greatly. You don't know the basic syntax for calling functions in C (which is similar to many other languages).

Comment: _"I dont know what part of the code is the problem ..."_ That's why I recommended you to step through your code line by line using the debugger, such you'll find out.

Comment: I have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You have several issues with you code.  First you are not calling your function correctly.  When you have

```
int start();
```

in `main()` it doesn't call the `start` function but instead declares a function named `start` that returns an `int` and takes nothing.  Knowing that you main function essential becomes

```
int main() {}
```

since you do nothing except set some variables that will never be used.  A good compiler with a warnings turned on should have at least told you that you had unused variables.

You are going to have this same issue everywhere else you call a function as you declare a function instead of calling it.

Your second issue will come up after you fix your function calls.  You will be using functions before you have defined them.  A easy way to fix this is to declare the function prototype of all of your functions before you define/use any of them so the compiler knows that the function is going to exist.

A third issue is you use

```
srand(time(0));
```

in the function `hunt()`.  This means that every time you call `hunt` you will reseed `rand`.  instead of doing that you can put `srand(time(0));` in main and then you will only seed `rand` once per execution of the program.

One last thing I see is none of your functions that are declared to return an `int` actually return anything.  If you declare that a function has a return value then you need to return something from the function.  If you do not want to return anything then you can make the return type `void` which means the function returns nothing.

Comment: i have now solved the third problem, but the other two are mysteries to me on how to fix them

Comment: @TylerBacon I suggest you read up on how to declare, define and use functions: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_functions.htm

Comment: @TylerBacon To call the `start` function you use `start();`, not `int start();`.